# Converting to duration from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I am trying to convert time duration from the format of **mm:ss.mss** to entirely milliseconds and back.

I've already have a working function for converting from milliseconds to duration but I cannot seem to get it the other way around.

Lets say for instance that I have the duration **32:29.060**, I want to convert it to milliseconds. For that I use this function:

```
function millisecondsToTime(ms, digits) {
    digits = digits || 12;
    return new Date(ms).toISOString().slice(23-digits, -1);
}

var a = millisecondsToTime(5549060, 9);
```

but whenever I try to convert back to time duration, I fail. I've tried parsing individually the minutes, seconds and milliseconds but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code that I've used for it:

```
var firstSplit = a.split(':')
var minutes = firstSplit[0]; //1 
var secondSplit = firstSplit[1].split('.');
var seconds = secondSplit[0]; //2
var millisec = secondSplit[1]; //3
var conversion = ((+minutes) * 60 + (+seconds) * 60 + (+millisec))*1000;
```

I have an input bar which takes the format of **mm:ss.mss** and I need to convert it to milliseconds. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you're trying to convert a date, which was already to string, back into a date format. That won't work.

Comment: I just said that I am trying to convert a duration of **time** to milliseconds and then back to duration of time. I'm not parsing date anywhere.

Comment: Isn't **toISOString()** converting the date into a string?

Answer (score 0):

you can just return a

```js
new Date(ms)
```

to get a date from ms.
And to get the same date as ms,

```js
date.getTime() // returns ms from date object
```

Full example:

```js
const ms = 5549060
const date = new Date(ms) // get a date from ms
console.log(date.getTime) // logs 5569060
```

If your input is a string in the format of mm:ss.mss, and you want to get a date from it, you can use moment.

```js
const moment = require('moment')
const date = moment('22:15.143', 'mm:ss.SSS') // get date from pre specified format
```

Comment: thanks but how can you return this from an input form of **1:23.384" ?

Comment: Pass that string into the moment function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string methods **indexOf()** and **substr()** to get the individual numbers out of your string and calculate the time accordingly.

I'm afraid though your **millisecondsToTime()** function isn't working properly.
5549060 milliseconds are roughly 92 minutes and it's returning 32:29.060

```js
function backToTime(time) {
  var index = time.indexOf(":");
  var minutes = time.substr(0, index);
  var seconds = time.substr(index + 1, time.indexOf(".") - (index + 1));
  var milliseconds = time.substr(time.indexOf(".") + 1, time.length);
  return parseInt(minutes * 60 * 1000) + parseInt(seconds * 1000) + parseInt(milliseconds);
}

console.log(backToTime("32:29.060"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to milliseconds is not working, this is basic math approach to both conversions:

```
let input = 5549060
//toDuration
let seconds = Math.floor(input / 1000);
let ms = input - seconds*1000;
let m = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
let s = seconds - m*60;

duration = m + ":" + s + "." + ms
console.log(duration)

//toMilliseconds
let holder = duration.split(":");
m = parseInt(holder[0]);
holder = holder[1].split(".");
s = parseInt(holder[0]);
ms = parseInt(holder[1]);

milliseconds = (m*60 + s)*1000 + ms
console.log(milliseconds)
```

If needed add check for ms length to add 0s, if you need it to have length of 3

Answer (score 0):

I think your milliseconds to duration converter will be broken for durations above 60 minutes. This is because using `Date` the minutes field will wrap over into the minutes after 59 seconds have passed. If you want to get good support for values beyond 59 in your first field, I think maybe moving to a regex-based parser and using multiplication and addition, division and modulo to extract and reduce the fields manually might be nice. Something like this maybe:[image]

```
var duration = ms => `${(ms / 60000) | 0}`.padStart(2, '0') + `:` + `${ms % 60000 / 1000 | 0}`.padStart(2, '0') + `.` + `${ms % 1000}`.padStart(3, '0')
var millisec = durat => (match => match && Number(match[1]) * 60000 + Number(match[2]) * 1000 + Number(match[3]))(/^([0-9]+)\:([0-5][0-9])\.([0-9]{3})$/.exec(durat))
```

You can see given the input `5549060`, this function provides output `92:29.60`, which is exactly 60 seconds greater than your own, and I believe to be correct. Maybe it's intentional for your usecase, but I can't imagine that being so desirable generally...